# Warning message when sourcing .vimrc

Tags: comments, vim, zsh

I am trying to set up a `.vimrc` file in my home directory. The only thing it contains is the following.

```
" Enable syntax highlighting
syntax on
```

Whenever I want to source the file running `. ~/.vimrc` this message is returned.

```
/Users/username/.vimrc:3: unmatched "
```

My working environment is the following.

- MacOS Lion 10.7.2
- zsh 4.3.12 (i386-apple-darwin11.2.0)
- [oh_my_zsh](http://git://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh.git)
- Terminal 2.2.1
- VIM 7.3

How can I get rid of this warning/error message. What does it mean?!

**EDIT**

When I try the same from `bash` it does not work either.

```
bash-3.2$ . ~/.vimrc 
bash: /Users/username/.vimrc: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: /Users/username/.vimrc: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Have you tried running `source ~/.vimrc`?

Comment: `. ~/.vimrc` is invalid to me. `source ~/.vimrc` is OK. And have you trid to remove the comment line: `"Enable syntax highlighting`?

Comment: When I remove the comment line it states: "syntax: command not found".

Comment: Why are you trying to source a vimscript file in bash? Vimscript isn't bash. That's like trying to compile python with gcc.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you can run `. ~/.bashrc` in console
but you should run `:source ~/.vimrc` in vim
vim will run `~/.vimrc` automatically, you don't need run it manually.

type `:ver` to check:

```
   system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME\_vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "$VIM\_vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME\_exrc"
  2nd user exrc file: "$VIM\_exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM\gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME\_gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "$VIM\_gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME\menu.vim"
```

Comment: My configuration looks similar `user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"`. Nonetheless, sourcing from the shell should also work, shouldn't it? I  manually sourcing it to see if my settings work.

Comment: @JJD: you cannot source a vim script in the shell(zsh). you should source it in vim. The syntax of source is `:source filename` or `:so filename`. The `dot(.)` is for string concatenation in vim.

Comment: So what you mean is that I can only source files like `.bash_rc` or `.zshrc` from the shell. But not configuration files meant to set up vim. Correct?

Comment: @JJD you are right. `~/.vimrc` only contains bunch of vim command which cannot be execute by `ksh`/`bash`.

Answer (score -1):

Put following code on head in your `~/.vimrc`.

```
"return" 2>&- || "exit"
```