# Vimrc error: "syntax: command not found"

Tags: vim

Everything worked fine a couple weeks ago and then boom! Out of no where I got this error from my .vimrc. I reduced it to the very ultimately basic version but nothing changed.

Ultimately superiorly basic version:

[image: Ultimately superiorly basic version]

Actual footage:

[image: Actual footage]

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457599/warning-message-when-sourcing-vimrc#comment51099201_8457599).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning message when sourcing .vimrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457599/warning-message-when-sourcing-vimrc)

Answer (score 30):

You are trying to source your `vimrc` in your shell, which doesn't make any sense *at all*.

Vim uses its own scripting language that is not understood by your shell and your shell uses its own scripting language that is not understood by Vim so there's no reason *whatsoever* to expect `$ source ~/.vimrc` (in your shell) or `:source ~/.bashrc` (in Vim) to do anything useful.

You can, however…

- source your vimrc from *within vim* via `:source ~/.vimrc`,
- or simply let Vim source it itself when it starts.

Comment: Do i have to source the .vimrc everytime when I start my vim

Comment: @MDNasirulIslam, no. Vim automatically tries to sources `~/.vimrc` at startup.