# Syntax for .vimrc not being understood by bash

Tags: linux, bash, vim

I've written multiple .vimrc files before, and every one of them has worked great - until this one.  I'm currently running LMDE 4 (Linux Mint Debian Edition 4), and some very odd behavior is coming up.  Here's a few examples of some test cases:

~/.vimrc

```
" Test comment
```

Terminal

```
usr@computer:~$ source ~/.vimrc
bash: /home/usr/.vimrc: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ':'
bash: /home/usr/.vimrc: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
usr@computer:~$
```

In other words, even if the .vimrc is nothing but a single comment line, it doesn't seem to be understood.

Here's another fun example...

.vimrc

```
" Test comment 1
set number
" Test comment 2
set expandtab
```

Terminal

```
usr@computer:~$ source .vimrc
 Test comment 1
set number
: command not found
usr@computer:~$
```

And, finally, if I exclude all comments...

.vimrc

```
set colorscheme default
```

Terminal

```
usr@computer:~$ source .vimrc
usr@computer:~$ vim .vimrc
Error detected while processing /home/usr/.vimrc:
line 1:
E518: Unknown option: colorscheme
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Note that it seems to source fine here, but when I go to reopen the file with vim, it spews out this error.  Also note that this seems to potentially be specific to colorscheme (does not happen if I were to do `set number` or `set expandtab`, presumably some other commands are also readable).

Any thoughts/ideas?  I'm seriously stumped.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.vimrc` is meant to be read by Vim, not Bash. And are you sure that these are the actual messages you're seeing? For example, the first one complains about a missing `:`, but it should really complain about a `"`. And again, Bash  can't run the commands in your `.vimrc`.

Comment: the `source` command should be run from inside vim

Comment: The error that actually comes from vim for the last attempt is because `colorscheme` is a command itself, not an option for `set`.

Comment: Right, thanks everyone.  It's been a little while since I cracked open a Linux box, so I just mixed up here.  Thanks again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning message when sourcing .vimrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457599/warning-message-when-sourcing-vimrc)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbash%5D+source+.vimrc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.vimrc` is a Vim script, not a shell script. Both Vim and shell have separate `source` commands which executes the commands in a file in Vim or shell, respectively.

`.vimrc` is sourced by Vim when Vim starts; it has nothing to do with the shell.