# Errors while sourcing .vimrc

Tags: vim

I am using bash terminal and in my .vimrc I have the following lines:

```
set number
"set tags+=/users/vinod/ctags_related/tags
imap 2s <SPACE><SPACE>
```

When I save and then try to source my .vimrc, I get the following errors:

```
bash: /users/vinod/.vimrc: line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: /users/vinod/.vimrc: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

The line number shown in the second error doesn't exist in my .vimrc

Why am I getting these errors? How can I fix them?

TIA

Vinod

Comment: By "source my .vimrc", it sounds like you are sourcing it in bash? Usually the `.vimrc` is sourced from Vim, not from Bash.

Comment: @xdhmoore I use source ~/.vimrc from a bash terminal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syntax for .vimrc not being understood by bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61819818/syntax-for-vimrc-not-being-understood-by-bash)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+bash%3A+.vimrc+syntax+error%3A+unexpected+end+of+file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are doing `source ~/.vimrc` from the terminal prompt, then you are getting errors you should expect. The `.vimrc` file contains vimscript, which only the vim program understands. Bash is giving you errors because it is not supposed to source that file. When you start vim, normally by just typing `vim` and hitting enter, vim will automatically source your `.vimrc`